# Fingerprint event capturing using javaApi?

Tags: java, sockets, fingerprint

Hi I have a javaAPi for the capturing events from the finger Print machine,I am connected  the machine by using TCP. I am not understanding how to capture events from the machine continually using xmlevent handler.

This API will have these methods.

```
public interface SBXPCXMLEventListener {
    public void OnReceiveEventXML(String eventXML);
}
public static native boolean StartEventCapture(long dwCommType, long dwParam1, long dwParam2);
```

If I am not understandable please ask me question i will clear.please apologies for my less information.

Answer (score 0):

You write this class, and pass an instance of this class to addXMLEventListener.

```
public class MyEventListener implements SBXPCXMLEventListener {

    @Override
    public void OnReceiveEventXML(String eventXML) {
        // Process the eventXML

    }

}
```

I don't have the documentation, so I have no idea what your XML looks like.  This tutorial for [Java XML processing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/) might help.

This is a Java class, so you can add your Java fields and a constructor to pass the values to your fields.

Comment: Shell i upload the documentation.